# Error combining separators using || in listofitems

Tags: comma-separated-list

I have noticed that `.-` may cause trouble if chosen as a separator with two or more other separators. Below minimal example compiles, but the line `\bar{(w1) .- (w2)}` that is commented out will throw the error "File ended while scanning use of `\readlist_i`." Surprisingly, `\bar{-.--.-}` works, but as soon as anything follows `.-`, even just a space, it breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\def\foo#1{%
    \setsepchar{-.||.-}%
    \readlist*\mylist{#1}%
    \mylistlen%
}
\def\bar#1{%
    \setsepchar{-.||.-||--}%
    \readlist*\mylist{#1}%
    \mylistlen%
}

\begin{document}
\foo{(w1) -. (w2)}
\foo{(w1) .- (w2)}
\foo{-.--.-}
\bar{(w1) -. (w2)}
\bar{(w1) -- (w2)}
% \bar{(w1) .- (w2)}
\bar{-.--.-}
\end{document}
```

Another separator list that causes trouble is `-.||..||--`. I understand that there may be several ways to divide a sequence of characters given that these separators overlap in characters, but for my envisioned inputs, this wouldn't be the case. Also, `-.--.-` is simply parsed from left to right, and I'd be happy with that.

So I'm wondering, Is there a rule for which separators can be combined with `||` and which ones cannot?

Comment: In the manual I see «It is not possible to select `|` as the *⟨delimiter⟩* because it would conflict with the logical OR, denoted “`||`” (see below). However, one can work around this limitation, at one’s own peril, writing “`\setsepchar{{|}}`”.»

Comment: I know. I am not trying to use `|` as delimiter, I am trying to use `||` as OR here.